# How to validate two fields in controllers in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have two fields selectbox1 and selectebox2 in form and I want to validate that they don't have same value. If they have same value return to form with error message. I am unable to do that validation.

In Controller :

```
$know_lang = $form->get('language_help')->getValue();
$need_lang = $form->get('language_need')->getValue();

 if($know_lang == $need_lang){
    $form->get('language_need')->setMessages(array('Please Select different language'));
   return false;
  }
```

Comment: You can use the zf2 validator http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.identical.html

Comment: show the code you added for validation

Comment: This is for Identical but I want to UnIdentical how can I get it. @KiwiJuicer

Comment: Ah ok. Your code looks correct. What is actually happening? Is the message not showing up? Except that you return false. You have to pass the form to the view. return [ 'form' => $form];

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got the solution for this.

In Controller

Try this

```
try {
     $this->checkEmailExist($need_lang,$know_lang);
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $form->setMessages(array(
                         'language_help' => array($e->getMessage())
                     ));
       return new ViewModel(array(
       'form' => $form
      ));
    }
```

And make another function

```
public function checkEmailExist($email){
        // Your Db Query
        if($row) {
            throw new \Exception("Email already exist");
        }
        return true;
    }
```